# Can one reach every state in phase-space from initial conditions on a codimension-1 submanifold?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields

Take the stereotypical ODE $\dot x = f(x)$ where $x \in R^n$.

Say now I take a compact, $n$-dimensional subset $P$ of my phase space in $R^n$. Can I always find a $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold S $\subset P$ such that all of $P$ can be reached from initial conditions in $S$? In other words, can I always foliate $P$ with orbits emerging from some submanifold $S$ with codimension 1?

If the answer is positive, what other assumptions would I need to guarantee that $S$ is connected, smooth and so on?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: No.  Let $f=0$ for example.

Comment: You might find the Flow-Box Theorem useful to compare to. The reachability of $P$ you ask for is difficult to test because it is a global property and nonlinear behaviour can obstruct that; just because locally some open set of $P$ is reachable in the manner you describe won't mean all of $P$ will be.